# How to do 10.1 + 3.4 ? (But the result is 13)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How to do 10.1 + 3.4 ? (But the result is 13)
The result need to be: 13.5.
How I can fix it ?

code:

```
           [appdelegate.object.moneyW replaceObjectAtIndex:[row intValue] withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [mangerMonetMuchS intValue]+[alertNumberB.text intValue]]];
```

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer at the moment, particularly as you've shown no code. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Can you add some code to make your question clear?

Comment: Is it giving you 13 or do you want it to give you 13?

Comment: [appdelegate.object.moneyW replaceObjectAtIndex:[row intValue] withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [mangerMonetMuchS intValue]+[alertNumberB.text intValue]]];

Comment: Since this is your first question i won't vote it down. But if you want people to be able to help you (and to be motivated to do it at all) you really should show some more effort. Take a look around SO and see how upvoted questions (or at least those with no downvotes) are formulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to assign that to an Int? Because if so, 13.5 will be truncated to exactly 13. Make sure all your variables are floating point numbers, not integers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using int value, use float value.

```
[appdelegate.object.moneyW replaceObjectAtIndex:[row intValue] withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [mangerMonetMuchS floatValue]+[alertNumberB.text floatValue]]];
```

PS: Why are you using NSNumber?

Comment: Thanks its work but it need to be @"%f",
And when I do it I see a lot of zero like that: 13.500000.

Comment: hmm... instead, how about using %@ and take away the floatValue method.

Comment: @gal050: then use @"%.1f" to limit the shown zeroes. And make sure that you accept this answer if it helped you solve your problem.